# What is the correct way to include headers between two files in C

Tags: c, header, include

I guess that's a pretty dumb question, but I'm facing a little problem in my C program:

Let's say I have file1.c and file2.c

I'm using in file1.c and file2.c a struct declared in file2.c
I'm also using file1.c functions inside file2.c

So what I did is that I put `#include "file1.h"` in file2.h and `#include "file2.h"` in file1.h...
But I have an infinite loop when compiling.

How can I fix this? Thanks

Comment: put both the header and the function in one header file, nd `#include` it in in both `file1.c` and `file2.c`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use include guard in both `file1.h` and `file2.h`. Something like

```
#ifndef FILE1_H_
#define FILE1_H_

/* ...
 * code
 */

#endif /* FILE1_H_ */
```

Answer (score 1):

Include guards, as mentioned by [@downhillFromHere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26263463/1430833), are one answer. All header files should have include guards, unless you have a very good reason otherwise.

However, your description doesn't make it clear why you need `file1.h` to include `file2.h` and vice versa. Header files describe an interface. If the interfaces are dependent, then you should think about combining them into a single header: `file.h`.  If the interfaces described in `file1.h` and `file2.h` are independent, then they shouldn't include each other. The proper way to expose independent interfaces is to have `file1.c` and `file2.c` include both headers.

In both `file1.c` and `file2.c`:

```
#include "file1.h"
#include "file2.h"
```

This keeps the interfaces decoupled, which allows you to reason about the independent interfaces separately, reduces mistakes, and can greatly reduce compile time.